# JAX WS RS JPA não retorna relação OneToMany no JSON

Tags: java, json, restful, jax-ws

Em minha relação, um Chamado está relacionado a muitos Históricos.
A chave do Chamado está presente em cada Histórico.
Ao consultar um Histórico pelo código, existe uma relação @ManyToOne que retorna o Chamado ao qual pertence o histórico.
Ao consultar o Chamado, a resposta deveria conter o Chamado consultado e todos os Históricos relacionados a esse Chamado. Esta relação está mapeada no modelo Chamado como @OneToMany.

É possível instanciar na classe a Collection Histórico e gerar um output no console, porém o histórico não é enviado no JSON para o cliente.

Obs: Todas as classes JPA foram geradas automaticamente a partir do NetBeans, utilizando a opção "Novo > Classe de Entidade do Banco de Dados...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após muitas pesquisas, cheguei na seguinte solução.

O modelo Chamado deve conter no atributo Collection Historico a anotação que informa o tipo de relação e como parâmetro deve ser passado o tipo de load: LAZY ou EAGER. No meu caso o EAGER foi necessário para sempre trazer o histórico.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "chamado", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonManagedReference
private Collection<Historico> historicoCollection;
```

Na classe Historico o mapeamento fica dessa forma.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "chamado", referencedColumnName = "codigo")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Chamado chamado;
```

Também tive de excluir a anotação @XmlTransiente.

```
//@XmlTransient
public Collection<Historico> getHistoricoCollection() {
    return historicoCollection;
}
```

Como mostra na seguinte pergunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752912/jax-rs-expose-onetomany-entities-in-get

Após excluir a anotação @XmlTransiente na anotação, é gerado um erro de recursividade.
Para tanto é explicado [neste link](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html) a solução para o problema, que é apenas informar quem é a classe que contem a relação, através das anotações @JsonBackReference e @JsonManagedReference.